# Setting up PolicySets for Username token Authentication in WMB

Tags: ws-security

As per http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1008_fan/1008_fan.html  I am trying to setup Policy Set and Policybinding in IBM Websphere Message Broker.

My query is,we setup Policy set and Policy binding and use those in Message flow SOAP nodes inorder to use the policies on the incoming or outgoing messages.
I have also read that the WSDL should contain "WS-Policy" headers only then the Policy sets can be applied.But the PI in this link does not contain WSDL with "WS-Policy" security headers.So,what is the actual procedure?Doesnt the WSDL need to be amended with this Policy related headers?Or defining Policy and binding in WMB explorer and using the name of policies in SOAP nodes is fine without having any Policy information in WSDL?Kindly let me know.

Comment: I raised a PMR on this.And got updates from IBM that current versions of WMB does not have any features as this.

Comment: I have raised RFE on this.